# How to trigger state update with react-navigation?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-state-management, react-state

In my React Native application I'm trying to change state and trigger a re-render of a component. It should be done when `NavBottom` calls `this.props.navigation.navigate('captureView')` to navigate to `CaptureView`. The state update should reset the `CaptureView` photo state variable back to its original value.

How can state be changed in React Native with `react-navigation` on `navigate`? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

`CaptureView` is part of `CaptureStack`

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const CaptureStack = createStackNavigator({
    captureView: CaptureView,
    detailView: DetailView,
    reportView: ReportView,

});

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    capture: CaptureStack,
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'capture',
    tabBarComponent: NavBottom
});
```

`CaptureView.js`:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions, NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

class CaptureView extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {}

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("CaptureView: constructor(props)");
    }

    componentDidMount() { // called just once
        console.log("CaptureView: componentDidMount()");
        // this.setState = { // undefined???
        //     photo: null // this needs to be RESET
        // };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("CaptureView: componentWillUnmount()");
    }

    async onButtonPress() {
        CameraService.takePicture().then((photo)=>{
            this.setState({
                photo: photo
            });

            // More actions

            this.props.navigation.navigate(
                "detailView",
                {
                    id: 'DetailView',
                    photo
                }
            );

        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Camera
                cameraSetter={(cam) => {
                    CameraService.setCamera(cam)
                }}
                photo={this.state.photo}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                <Text>TAKE PHOTO</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in other part of the application there is a button to navigate back to CaptureView.

`NavBottom.js`:

```
export default class NavBottom extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('captureView')}>
                    <Text>CAMERA</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View >);
    }
}
```

Notes

I've tried different ways from ReactJS (not React Native) documentation that failed:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount - `componentDidMount()` seems to bee the recommended way in documentation, but in my application it gets called ONLY ONCE?
- Even when `componentDidMount()` is called once at the beginning, but even then `this.setState()` is undefined. It's strange, the documentation says it should be available

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using navigation events to reset the state of your CaptureView component?

I think `onWillFocus` might do the trick.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Comment: Should work in your case.  In general (screen) components will remain mounted as long as they exists in a stack somewhere, so when you navigate back to that screen componentDidMount will not trigger.  But if you use navigation.goBack() to pop the screen off the stack, it will actually unmount, therefore componentDidMount will be exectured the next time we navigate to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation doesn't re-render a component in a stack that resides in Tab Naviagtor
in order perform forceful re-render than you can use event listener like this

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this._navListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
         //perform any action you want, place your logic here
        });

    }
```

you can also use React Navigation's HOC **withNavigation** this pass a ( *isFocused* ) prop to the connected component

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused){
//place your desired logic here
}

}
```

#### Usage of withNavigation

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';
 ...
 ...
 ...

export default withNavigationFocus(YourComponent)
```